# Change font color in Kendo datepicker

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

I need to change the font color of the calendar that appears after clicking on a Kendo datepicker widget. I have been able to change the font size, the background color, but I can't seem to be able to change the font color to display the calendar header (month), week days, or days of the month.

Is there a way to do it, or perhaps this is not a supported feature in Kendo Calendar right now?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following in your custom css file or in the page header style

```
.k-calendar .k-header .k-link {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

Use the browser developer tool F12 and look at the style involved in it and update it as you like.

Comment: It worked like a charm! Just for future reference, here are the classes I used to modify the appearance of all the calendar elements:.k-calendar .k-header .k-link {
    color: #ff0000;
}

.k-calendar .k-link {
    color: #ff0000;
}

.k-calendar th {
    color: #ff0000;
}